# How to make a column from Pandas a variable?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

So I have this fine code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:00:00")

url = 'https://api.energidataservice.dk/dataset/Elspotprices?filter={%22PriceArea%22:[%22DK1%22]}&limit=50'
r = requests.get(url)
json = r.json()


# HourUTC   HourDK  SpotPriceDKK    SpotPriceEUR

df = pd.DataFrame(json['records'])
df2 = df.loc[df['HourDK'] == dt_string]
df2 = df2.astype({'SpotPriceDKK': 'float'})

print(df2['SpotPriceDKK'].values)
```

When running the program it's giving me what I want, like this:

```
[1053.52002]
```

But I cant make it a variable and subtract and add to it. How can you change this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand what you mean by "make it a variable" (possibly because you have a wrong idea about what "variable" means). In your program, for example, `now`, `dt_string`, `url`, `r`, `json`, `df` and `df2` are all variables, and it seems pretty clear that you know how to "make" some value into a variable: by assigning it. Suppose, for example, we write `value = df2['SpotPriceDKK'].values`. Then it is a variable. But I think this does not solve the problem?

Comment: do you mean you want a float?

Comment: I assume what you mean is that you want to get the **floating-point value** `1053.52002` out of the data, so that you can do arithmetic with it. But - what will you do, **if there is more than one** value? After all, `df2['SpotPriceDKK']` means a column of a DataFrame, right? What if there are multiple rows?

Comment: Where the code says `df2['SpotPriceDKK'].values`, what exactly do you think this means? In particular, what do you think is the **type** of the result that you get? **What effect** do you think the `.values` part has - **how do you think this is different** from the result of just `df2['SpotPriceDKK']`? (If you can't easily answer these questions, it might be a good idea to review a Python tutorial, before trying to use more advanced libraries like Pandas.)

Comment: You probably need to work on some basics. But you have done good so far, getting the value you need. Try `float(df2['SpotPriceDKK'].values)` to get a number you can work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you need to extract the single value. Your code returns a DataFrame, which you then slice as Series. You can directly get the value using [`squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.squeeze.html):

```
val = df.loc[df['HourDK'] == dt_string, 'SpotPriceDKK'].squeeze()
```

Output: `1053.52002`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you get only one number in you `df2['SpotPriceDKK']`, simply change the type of your variable to `int` or `float`:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:00:00")

url = 'https://api.energidataservice.dk/dataset/Elspotprices?filter={%22PriceArea%22:[%22DK1%22]}&limit=50'
r = requests.get(url)
json = r.json()


# HourUTC   HourDK  SpotPriceDKK    SpotPriceEUR

df = pd.DataFrame(json['records'])
df2 = df.loc[df['HourDK'] == dt_string]
df2 = df2.astype({'SpotPriceDKK': 'float'})

num = df2['SpotPriceDKK'].values
num_float = float(num)
print(num_float)
```

Output:

`1053.52002`